# Unity 2d Rigidbody; moving with the same speed faster in Y axis than in X axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason the spaceshooter that i want to do, when i programmed the movement using Rigidbody2d.velocity, it moves much faster in Y axis (as in acceleration too) then in X axis, and i don't know why. I checked input.manager for gravity in both axis; both are equal. Checked physics 2d, set both to 0 even thought it wouldnt affect anything since my rigidbody is set to Kinematic... I'm currently lost.

Code of the movement is the following:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
```

{
public GameObject player;

```
float moveSpeed = 3f;
public float min_y, max_y;
public float min_x, max_x;


public Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Start()
{
    class_selected = false;
    player = transform.gameObject;
    attack_timer = (float)characterStats.attackSpeed;

    cattack_timer = attack_timer ;
    rb = transform.Find("playerModel").gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    ...
    float yMov = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, yMov) * moveSpeed;
    print(rb.velocity.x);
    float xMov = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(xMov, rb.velocity.y) * moveSpeed;
    print(rb.velocity.y);
    ...
}
```

The rigidbody 2d is set to kinematic, gravity and sensitivity on both axis in input.manager are set to equal numbers... Tried debugging with print as you see, but in console they're printed equally the same... The project settings are most likely the default ones of a new empty 2d project in unity.

And if this isnt the correct way to move my character equally fast on both axis, which one is? Tried many videos but none work, and using transform movement wasnt recommended.

Comment: Try using this for late update: rb.velocity = new Vector2(xMov, yMov). Try adding velocity at the same time. Declare the y/xMov before the same way.

Comment: alright let me try

Comment: thanks ken!! worked exactly as you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ken posted, using rb.velocity = new Vector2(xMov,yMov) *moveSpeed fixes this completely, thank you so much ken!!!